# Eigenvalues of matrice.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need help with the following.

If $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ , $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, then $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

If $A$ is a reflective matrix, then $A^2 = I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$, then $1$ and(!) $-1$ are possible eigenvalues of $A$.

Example: $A=-I_2$. $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A^2$ has the Eigenvalue $1$, with the corresponding Eigenvector $v$ we have

$$(A^2-I)v=(A+I)(A-I)v=(A-I)(A+I)v=0.$$

This can arise with both $1$ or $-1$ for the Eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You can power matrix by this identity: $A^n = BD^nB^{-1}$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues, you got from solving the equation $det(A-\lambda E) = 0$, on its diagonal. $B$ is the matrix that consists of the eigenvectors. So even $A^n$ have the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$.